# Using glm in R to solve simple equation

Tags: r, glm

I have some data from a poisson distribution and have a simple equation I want to solve using glm.

The mathematical equation is observed = y * expected.

I have the observed and expected data and want to use glm to find the optimal value of y which I need to multiply expected by to get observed. I also want to get confidence intervals for y.

Should I be doing something like this

```
glm(observed ~ expected + offset(log(expected)) + 0, family = 'poisson', data = dataDF)
```

Then taking the exponential of the coefficient? I tried this but the value given is pretty different to what I get when I divide the sum of the observed by the sum of the expected, and I thought these should be similar.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Do you want `observed = y(expected)`, i.e. a function `y`, or do you want, as your text states,  `observed = y * expected` ?

Comment: yes observed = y * expected sorry.

Comment: Ben - The data I am using is 1000's of rows long (and also confidential) so can't show this to make it reproducible I'm afraid. I could try and create a dummy set but not entirely sure how to create data with the same properties as mine. Basically the data follows a poisson distribution, expected is  an expected value for one data point and observed is an integer value of what we actually see, so is not independent of the expected value - if the expected value is high then the observed value is more likely to be high. Basically I wanted to know if the R formula I gave is equivalent to the math

Comment: If all you want is  `Obs = y* Ex`, then why can't you just use a simple `lm` linear fit?

Comment: I agree with Carl, it seems like you want a simple linear regression. When you do a poisson glm `y~x`, you are modeling `log(y)` as a function of `x`. Just because your data is poisson doesn't necessarily mean you need to use a poisson regression model. It's more important what the error terms in your model are -- what is the distribution of the `oserved minus k * expected` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 logFac <- coef( glm(observed ~ offset(expected) , family = 'poisson', data = dataDF))
 Fac <- exp( logFac[1] )  # That's the intercept term
```

That model is really : `observed ~ 1 + offset(expected)` and since it's being estimated on a log scale, the intercept becomes that conversion factor to convert between 'expected' and 'observed'. The negative comments are evidence that you *should* have posted on CrossValidated.com where general statistics methods questions are more welcomed.